# Qurl not defined in pyqt

Tags: python, import, pyqt, pyqt4

Am learning to program python with qt using eric ide. But there seems to be one error i get.

Its says Global Qurl not defined or something. How can I define Qurl?

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow

from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignature
from Ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    """
    Class documentation goes here.
    """
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        """
        Constructor
        """
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    @pyqtSignature("")
    def on_btnNavigate_released(self):
        """
        Public slot invoked when the user clicks the Navigate Button .
        """
        self.webView.load(QUrl("http://qt.nokia.com/"));
```

Am following [this](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/tutorials/MiniBrowser/index.html) tutorial

Answer (score 4):

The code you posted is mostly auto-generated by the Eric4 IDE as part of the tutorial you posted a link to.

If you read [this page](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/tutorials/MiniBrowser/chapter3.html) of the tutorial carefully, it mentions importing `QUrl` in the paragraph following a code snippet for the `on_btnNavigate_released` method (near the bottom of the page):

> Notice that for this to work, we have to import QUrl (take a look at the source code accompanying the tutorial).

Although, to be fair to you, the source code snippet *doesn't* actually show the relevant import line! It should probably look something more like this:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignature, QUrl
...

@pyqtSignature("")
def on_btnNavigate_released(self):
    """
    Slot documentation goes here.
    """
    self.webView.setUrl(QUrl(self.txtUrl.text()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't import `QUrl` from anywhere. Do this:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
```

Note that you could also just import `QUrl` from `QtCore`, but a `*` import here is commonplace, since `QtCore` is huge and all classes have the `Q` prefix so it's not hard to guess where they came from. This is a matter of style of course, but personally I do use `*` imports from `QtCore` and `QtGui`. The PyQt book samples do the same.

Comment: I actually don't think its considered commonplace to do `from PyQt4.QtCore import *` because it can clutter the root namespace. Thats why pyuic4 generates its code with imports like `from PyQt4 import QtCore`. Its a bad habit I also try to get myself to stop doing.

Comment: @jdi. Yes, I agree about starred imports, particularly since Qt split up its namespaces with version 4. In general, and especially for learning purposes and example code, the "long-hand" form can often be much clearer. Having said that, in my own code, I usually prefer to import each item explicitly (as in the tutorial) rather than import `QtCore`, `QtGui`, etc. But the main thing is: don't throw away namespace information!